# How to connect to SQL server via TCP/IP which is server site using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, tcp, connection

Everyone. 
I've got some questions here..
I'm using C# and trying to connect the other computer which is server site.
The server site has been built a large database and it can be accessed by SQL server manager 2012.
All I'm trying is to read the data in that database then convert to the other file.
The other project test in my computer works(self-connection), but 
Here's my sqlconnection string:

```
string sqlstring = @"Data Source=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Database; Integrated Security=False; Connect Timeout=30;User ID=sa;Password=XXXXXXX";
```

Do I need to add "AttachDbFilename" into there?

or even database path?

```
AttachDbFilename=""C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Databasename.mdf"
```

Because the results are "sa log in failed" or "it couldn't find the database file"..
Is there any good advice? thank you guys!

Comment: first try in sql manager that username and password are corrct or not

Comment: It works in sql manager

Comment: in 90% of this case is due to password or username incorrect

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really know what arguments the connection string takes you may want to look into the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Here is a short code snippet:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder connString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
connString.UserID="sa";
connString.Password = "XXXX";
connString.DataSource = "XXXX"; //if you need to specify a port write
                                // the portnumber with a ',' behind the address
connString.InitialCatalouge = "MyDatabaseName";
connString.IntegratedSecurity = false; //set this one true if you want to use windows
                                       //authentification instead of sql authentification
string myconnectionstring = connString.ConnectionString;
```

It is a bad idea to use the super user, consider making a user that has only the privileges you need for your application to minimize security risks.